# can open webapp but not tomcat home page

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

When I deploy a webapp to a server by eclipse i can visit the webapp's sites with external browsers with no problems.
But I can't open localhost:8080 to visit tomcat's own page.how so?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Eclipse will not use the web container (tomcat in your case) files directly. It will copies some required files into `<your_workspace>/.metadata/.plugin/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/` and run server from there.

The `localhost:8080` page in tomcat are actually a default webapp call `ROOT`, you can find it in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT`.

When Eclipse copies web container files, it **DOSE NOT** include deployed application, that's the reason you cannot see root page.